# Shubnikov-de-Haas effect and Quantum Hall effect

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-hall-effect, hall-effect, quantum-transport

I am wondering if these two phenomena are two names for the same thing or whether these are distinct effects and there are situation where one appears, but the other one doesn't?

Both seem to produce magnetoresistance features at a certain period in $1/B$. And both occur at low temperatures and high magnetic fields. Both produce "stair"-like Hall resistance and oscillatory longitudinal resistance. I.e. both seem to be driven by circular orbits of charge carriers in low-scattering materials.

Is there a phenomenological difference between them? (Not looking so much for a mathematical difference)

Comment: [The Shubnikov -de Haas (SdH) oscillations occur at the lower fields while the Quantum Hall (QH) oscillations occur at the higher fields](https://globaljournals.org/GJSFR_Volume14/3-Theory-of-Shubnikov-De-Haas.pdf)

Comment: @Farcher what is the parameter that is given in µA in this paper ? I first thought it is current (obviously), but then I saw that they measure a curve at 
"0 µA", which isn't really possible if that describes the probe current, right?

Comment: @Farcher there is no emf at constant magnetic field... But regardless: If I get the paper correctly, then they say that QHE and SdHE actually have opposite signs in the longitudinal resistance; and that the QHE is more robust, so is dominant at high "µA"s. And there should be some intermediate "µA"s where the two sort of cancel eachother ?! I have a hard time confirming this interpretation using other sources.

Comment: Figure 1 caption - *at various bias-induced currents* and [Shubnikov-de Haas oscillations of a single layer graphene under dc current bias](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.3678.pdf) which shows the experimental setup.

Comment: @Farcher Thanks for the paper link. They perform AC transport which is superimposed on a varying DC bias current.